# How to filter a dataframe by multiple columns and add a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

```
df = mdb.read_table(mdbfile, "table")
invoices = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=';')

lst = df[(df['El4'] == el4)] #contains specific rows of df

for i, row in lst.iterrows():
    prop = row['propertyid']
    mouvement = (row['Mouvements']*-1)

    a = invoices[(invoices['propertyReference'] == prop) & (invoices.invoiceGrossAmount == mouvement)]
    invoiceid = a['invoiceId'].values

    mouvement = (mouvement*-1)

    if df[(df.propertyid == prop) & (df.Mouvements == mouvement)]:
        df['id'] = invoiceid
```

I receive the following error:

```
The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I would like to fill in specific values (`invoiceId`) in the rows of the dataframe where `propertyid` equals `prop` and `mouvements` equals `mouvement`.

Comment: Is the error being occurring at the `if df[(df.propertyid == prop) & (df.Mouvements == mouvement)]:` line?

Comment: Seems like you could use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to do this.  Specify the merge criteria as you outlined in your post.

Comment: @dubbdan Yes in that line indeed

Comment: Can you post a sample of `lst` and `invoices`? I think you need to merge your dataframes, rather than use logical statements.

Comment: @dubbbdan Thank you very much for your reply! You implement it almost right. Actually I do not want to merge my tables. I need to fill in invoiceid (of table 1) in table 2 only if 'propertyid' in df matches with 'propertyReference' in invoices and if 'Mouvements' in df matches with 'invoiceGrossAmount'.

Comment: What are table 1 and table 2? In your original post, you talked about `df` and `invoices`. Could you provide an example of the contents of both tables to show what you'd like the results to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment.  It seems like you're just trying to join (or, in pandas terminology, a [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)).

Let's start with your source data:

```
df = mdb.read_table(mdbfile, "table")
invoices = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=';')
```

From here, we want to try to join the data:

```
df = df.merge(invoices, how='left', left_on=['propertyid', 'Mouvements'], right_on=['propertyReference', 'invoiceGrossAmount'])
```

In this join, I'm assuming that `'propertyid'` in `df` matches with `'propertyReference'` in `invoices` and that `'Mouvements'` in `df` matches with `'invoiceGrossAmount'` in `invoices`.  You can adjust as needed.

We're using a left join because we want `null` values in the original `df` when we can't find a match in `invoices` rather than not including those rows (in which case we'd use `how='inner'` instead).

No need to use a `for` loop this way.  I remember reading somewhere that if you're using a loop with pandas, there's a good chance there's a better way to do it with a built-in pandas method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! You implement it almost right. Actually I do not want to merge my tables. I need to fill in invoiceid (of table 1) in table 2 only if 'propertyid' in df matches with 'propertyReference' in invoices and if 'Mouvements' in df matches with 'invoiceGrossAmount'.

Comment: @ChristianVandeKoppel, What are table 1 and table 2?  In your original post, you talked about `df` and `invoices`.  Could you provide an example of the contents of both tables to show what you'd like the results to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use the [combine first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) method.

To use this method, you need to ensure the index in both data frames are equal.  Something like:

```
# Its not clear is the sign on Movement needs to be changed to merge with invoices. If so, comment out the line below
df.loc[:,'Mouvement] = df.loc[:,'Mouvement]*-1
df = df.set_index('propertyid','Mouvement')
invoices = invoices.set_index('propertyReference', 'invoiceGrossAmount')
df = df.combine_first(invoices)
```

This is very similar to the `merge` method @RagingRoosevelt suggested.